# how to create drop down list in jquery grid.?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my view here. I've posted my view,controller and jsonHelper.cs here for your reference. Please go through this. And attached a screen shot of my problem.

Sir i've pasted all my code here above. And i want 'Column Names' in Drop down list. I hope you can help me.??

```
//SchemaCreation View
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var TableWidth = null;
            var TableHeight = null;
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                //debugger;
                TableWidth = $("#list").width();
                TableHeight = $("#Div1").height();
            });
            jQuery(document).ready(function ()
            {
                //debugger;
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Schema/GetGridData?DataSource=' + '@ViewData["ServerName"]' + '&InitialCatalog=' + '@ViewData["DataBaseName"]' + '&UserName=' + '@ViewData["UserName"]' + '&PassWord=' + '@ViewData["PassWord"]',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames: ['Table Names', 'Column Names'],
                    colModel: [
                                 { name: 'Table Names', index: 'Table Names', width: 40, align: 'left', Style:'padding-left:15px;'},
                                 { name: 'Column Names', index: 'Column Names', width: 40, align: 'left'},//, width: 80, formatter: 'select', type:'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: "1:One;2:Two" } }
                              ],
                    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                    sortname: 'Table Names',
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    multiselect: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    width: TableWidth,
                    Height: 500,
                    scroll: true,
                    //caption: 'My first grid'
                });
            });
            </script>



    //SchemaController:-

    public ActionResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string DataSource, string InitialCatalog, string UserName, string PassWord)
            {
                DataSource = CrossCutting.EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(DataSource, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptDecryptKey"]);
                InitialCatalog = CrossCutting.EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(InitialCatalog, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptDecryptKey"]);
                UserName = CrossCutting.EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(UserName, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptDecryptKey"]);
                PassWord = CrossCutting.EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(PassWord, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptDecryptKey"]);

                return Content(JsonHelper.JsonForJqgrid(GetDataTable(sidx, sord, page, rows, DataSource, InitialCatalog, UserName, PassWord), rows, GetTotalCount(DataSource, InitialCatalog, UserName, PassWord), page), "application/json");
            }

            public DataTable GetDataTable(string sidx, string sord, int page, int pageSize, string DataSource, string InitialCatalog, string UserName, string PassWord)
            {
                int startIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize;
                int endIndex = page * pageSize;
                string sql = "select name from sys.tables";
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string connString = "Data Source=" + DataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + InitialCatalog + ";User ID=" + UserName + ";pwd=" + PassWord;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                var rows = adap.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }

            public int GetTotalCount(string DataSource, string InitialCatalog, string UserName, string PassWord)
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = null;
                string connString = "Data Source=" + DataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + InitialCatalog + ";User ID=" + UserName + ";pwd=" + PassWord;
                try
                {
                    string cmdText = "select name from sys.tables";
                    List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();
                    using (sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(connString))
                    {
                        sqlConnection2.Open();
                        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection2))
                        {
                            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                tablenames.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                                //Count = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return tablenames.Count();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (ConnectionState.Closed != sqlConnection2.State)
                        {
                            sqlConnection2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            }


    //JsonHelper.cs:-

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;

    namespace RuleEngine.Helper
    {
        public class JsonHelper
        {
            public static string JsonForJqgrid(DataTable dt, int pageSize, int totalRecords, int page)
            {
                string connString = "Data Source=" + "po8lt8zdqt.database.windows.net" + ";Initial Catalog=" + "iNubeRSBYClaims2" + ";User ID=" + "inubeadmin" + ";pwd=" + "Ravi*vikram123";
                string cmdText = "SELECT table_name,column_name FROM information_schema.columns Group By table_name,column_name ORDER BY table_name,column_name";

                List<SchemaCreation> AllTableAndColumnsName = new List<SchemaCreation>();
                using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    SqlConn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, SqlConn))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader Reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (Reader.Read())
                        {
                            AllTableAndColumnsName.Add(new SchemaCreation { Table_Names = Reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), Column_Names = Reader.GetValue(1).ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                }

                //List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string>();
                int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
                StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                jsonBuilder.Append("{");
                jsonBuilder.Append("\"total\":" + totalPages + ",\"page\":" + page + ",\"records\":" + (totalRecords) + ",\"rows\"");
                jsonBuilder.Append(":[");
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    jsonBuilder.Append("{\"i\":" + (i) + ",\"cell\":[");
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        jsonBuilder.Append("\"");
                        jsonBuilder.Append(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                        jsonBuilder.Append("\",");

                        List<string> ColumnNames = new List<string>();
                        string EachTableName = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                        ColumnNames = AllTableAndColumnsName.Where(p => p.Table_Names == EachTableName).Select(sw => sw.Column_Names).ToList();

                        jsonBuilder.Append("\"");
                        foreach (var EachColName in ColumnNames)
                        {
                            jsonBuilder.Append(EachColName);
                            jsonBuilder.Append(",");
                        }
                        jsonBuilder.Append("\",");

                    }
                    jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
                    jsonBuilder.Append("]},");
                }
                jsonBuilder.Remove(jsonBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
                jsonBuilder.Append("]");
                jsonBuilder.Append("}");
                return jsonBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }

        public class SchemaCreation
        {
            public string Table_Names { get; set; }

            public string Column_Names { get; set; }

            public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: In colModel, make sure `name` and `index` properties uses your object property name. I guess it should be something like `ColumnName`, not sure how you defined

Comment: yes sir., i want to create dropdownlist in second column of the jqGrid

Comment: how can i send my jqGrid screen shot.??i found no option here.

Comment: While you edit your question you can see a toolbar with image icon. Make use of it

Comment: What error are you getting here ?

Comment: Sir i've edited my question and posted complete code above. Plz check the above code and help me.

Comment: use firebug and see GetGridData method is called,trace the error, you will find yourself

Answer (score 0):

In jQgrid's colModel, `name` and `index` properties uses your C# object property name. I guess it should be something like `ColumnName`, not sure how you defined. Please change it accordingly like

```
colModel: [
        { name: 'TableName', index: 'TableName', width: 40, align: 'left',
                                               Style:'padding-left:15px;'},
        { name: 'ColumnName', index: 'ColumnName', width: 40, align: 'left', 
          width: 80, formatter: 'select', type:'select', edittype: 'select', 
          editoptions: { value: "1:One;2:Two" } }
   ]
```

Comment: My problem is still continuing. Can anybody help me there.??

Comment: Murali Murugesan sir., can yo help me here.??

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel: [
                { name: 'Table_Names', index: 'Table_Names', width: 40, align: 'left', Style:'padding-left:15px;'},
                { name: 'Column_Names', index: 'Column_Names', width: 40, align: 'left', width: 80, formatter: 'select', type:'select', edittype: 'select',
                editoptions:{
                dataUrl: '/Schema/GetGridData?DataSource=' + '@ViewData["ServerName"]' + '&InitialCatalog=' + '@ViewData["DataBaseName"]' + '&UserName=' + '@ViewData["UserName"]' + '&PassWord=' + '@ViewData["PassWord"]',
                buildSelect: function (data) {
                             var response, s = '<select>', i;
                             response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                             if (response && response.length) {
                                 $.each(response, function (i) {
                                     s += '<option value="' + this.Column_Names + '">' + this.Column_Names+ '</option>';
                                 });
                             }
                             return s + '</select>';
                         }
    }}]
```

I think now you can get the values now.If you don't then see in firebug-> Console, what json has returned for you.If you want all the value in the